mount.cifs says permission denied yet GVFS is able to mount with same credentials
I have reinstalled Fedora 40 server (without SELinux) after a disk failure and despite using the same configuration as previously, I now can't mount the share with mount.cifs but I can mount it using Gnome/GVFS.
Whatever I try I get permission denied with mount.cifs.
On the client
(also running Fedora 40, but workstation):
sudo mount -t cifs -vvv //nas/stuff/ /nas/stuff \
  -o 'user=wilma,domain=SAMBA,pass=thePasswordHere,uid=1000,gid=1000'

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.251,unc=\\nas\stuff,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=wilma,domain=SAMBA,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

sudo dmesg |tail

[134542.717594] CIFS: enabling forceuid mount option implicitly because uid= option is specified
[134542.717597] CIFS: enabling forcegid mount option implicitly because gid= option is specified
[134542.717598] CIFS: Attempting to mount //nas/stuff                                         
[134542.757040] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE                      
[134542.757059] CIFS: VFS: \\nas Send error in SessSetup = -13                                
[134542.757081] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13                                

1000 is the uid/gid of my user on the client.
On the server
/etc/samba/smb.conf:
[global]
  workgroup = SAMBA
  security = user
  passdb backend = tdbsam

  interfaces = 192.168.1.251/0 enp1s0
  hosts allow = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24
  hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0

[stuff]
   comment = Stuff
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
   path = /mnt/drive/files/stuff/
   force user = wilma
   force group = wilma
   force directory mode = 775
   force create mode = 664


Things I've tried

sec=ntlm sec=ntlmssp
not specifying uid and gid
adding vers=3.0
triple checking the password + username!
different and no value for domain
specifying domain via workgroup=SAMBA
checking the server's firewall allows samba and is not blocking any packets

